# Android camera (deprecated) preview resizes when recording

Tags: android, camera

The problem appears on my `Nexus 6P` device. After going through all the motions to detect optimal previews, aspect ratios, video sizes etc, I end up with the following:

**SurfaceView dimens** 2392x1440 (full screen)
Once re-measured with the aspect ratio of the camera preview resolution, this changes to 2560x1440 or 2392x1351 depending on the calculation method.

**Camera preview size**: 1920x1080

This is set on the camera params using `setPreviewSize()`:
`params.setPreviewSize(mOptimalPreviewSizes.width, mOptimalPreviewSizes.height);`

**Media recorder video size**: 1920x1080 (forced by the settings)

This is set on the media recorder:
             `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mOptimalVideoSize.width, mOptimalVideoSize.height);`

When I click the record button, the camera preview 'zooms in', i.e. resizes to video size. If I change the video size setting to for example 3840x2160, the preview works fine with no resizing.

I was under impression that it is possible to set video size separatly to the preview size, so I'm a bit confused to why I'm seeing this and how can I work around this.

EDIT:

As an example, OpenCamera seems to be able to separate preview surface resolution from video resolution. https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sourceforge/opencamera/

To make sure, I've added a line just before  `video_recorder.prepare();` to set a custom video size (`video_recorder.setVideoSize(640,480);`). The preview surface was still measuring near full screen at 2392x1351, and camera preview was still set to 1920x1080. I've also double checked the resulting video and it was 640x480 as expected. Unfortunately I cannot see anything in their code that would indicate how this is achieved.

EDIT 2:

I've also noticed that this 'zooming' action always happens to a specific resolution/value. Regardless of whether I'm recording at 1920x1080 or 320x200, the preview gets zoomed and looses about a cm of the picture that was available before the recording started. The end video has the expected cropping in relation to the resolution.

Comment: Since there are three camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`, and `MediaRecorder`), I recommend that you post some code demonstrating your problem, so if nothing else, we can see which APIs you are using.

Comment: This particular problem happens using lthe egacy `android.hardware.Camera` and `MediaRecorder` with a `SurfaceView`. There are multiple classes with literally thousands lines of code so I'm not sure what would be helpful to post. The three values shown in the question are active just before I run `mMediaRecorder.start();` How I calculate them doesn't really matter as the problem seems to be related to the resolution I'm setting for `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize` being lower than the size of the surface view available.

Comment: When you set MediaRecorder video size, this does change the preview. This is how camera firmware works. If you want to see higher resolution on screen, but only compress lower res video, you should use some other class, e.g. MediaCodec.

Comment: @AlexCohn I think there might be a parameter or something to avoid this. OpenCamera for example uses `MediaRecorder` and allows the user to set video resolution lower than the preview resolution.

Comment: I don't see justification to your words in https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera/blob/master/src/com/almalence/plugins/capture/video/VideoCapturePlugin.java. [SetCameraPreviewSize()](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera/blob/master/src/com/almalence/plugins/capture/video/VideoCapturePlugin.java#L1221) is tuned to the size used by recorder.

Comment: I was referring to the different OpenCamera - looks like there's several :) https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sourceforge/opencamera/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the video stabilisation. I suppose this actually makes sense as stabilising against shakes usually requires cropping and when the preview resolution is already significantly lower than the surface size, it causes the picture to 'jump' or 'zoom' in. Removing video stabilisation fixes the issue.

Comment: This didnt fix the issue for me, could you show a code example